# Cakephp 2.0 Auth AND Basic Authentication

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, authentication

I'm upgrading a CakePHP 1.3 app to 2.0.3.

Previously, I was able to use the Auth component to log users in, and use the Security component to emulate Basic HTTP authentication. (as if I had setup an .htaccess file to password protect a page)

I used to do this:

```
$this->Security->loginOptions = array('type'=>'basic','realm'=>'training');
$this->Security->loginUsers = array("student"=>"student2010");
$this->Security->requireLogin();
```

Now it appears that even if I use:

```
public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array('Basic')
        )
    );
```

It still wants to use my User model and database. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the **BaseAuthenticate** and **BasicAuthenticate** classes would suggest that Cake no longer supports defining users and passwords that way.

You would probably have to extend the **BasicAuthenticate** class and override it's **getUser()** method.

Perhaps someone else could shed some light on this?

Comment: Yeah, this was a consideration. I may end up doing this.